# whether a polynomial is irreducible or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

Let $$I=\langle x^4+3x^2+2\rangle$$ and $F=\mathbb{Q}[x]/I$

The question is whether $F$ is a field or not.

I know how to proceed this problem. I'm confusing with irreducibility of the given polynomial

Here, $x^4+3x^2+2=0$ implies $x^4+3x^2=-2$. This happens only $x \in \mathbb{C}$. So the polynomial has no root in $\mathbb{Q}$ and hence irreducible.

However, $x^4+3x^2+2=(x^2+2)(x^2+1)$, so the given polynomial is reducible.

Where I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: The polynomial is reducible, so $F$ is not a field.

Comment: Here even though $x \in \mathbb{C}$, $x^2 \in \mathbb{Q}$. Since the polynomial does not involve an odd power of $x$, this is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Irreducibility over $\Bbb Q$ does not mean "has no rational root". As this
example shows, a polynomial may be written as a non-trivial product
but with no roots over $\Bbb Q$. The smallest degree where his happens is $4$ where a polynomial, as here, can be a product of two irreducible
quadratics.

Answer (score 0):

You are assuming that $p(x)$ has no roots in $\mathbb Q$ implies that $p(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Q$. This is true if the degree of $p(x)$ is $2$ or $3$, but not in general, as your own example shows.

Comment: This answer helps too. Thanks